# Importing external fonts to iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

How can I import external arabic and english fonts to my iPhone application ?

Comment: Do you mean use custom fonts in iOS app?

Comment: you want to add font on xCode, right?

Answer (score 4):

For importing Custom fonts in your iOS app

1. Add `.TTF` or `.OTF` font that you downloaded in your application.
2. Modify the `plist` file i.e. `application-info.plist` file.
3. Add the key "Fonts provided by application" in a new row.
4. and add each `.TTF` or `.OTF` file (of font) to each line.

[image: Info.plist Screen Shot]

and then in your `label` or `textfield`

```
yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_FONT" size:15];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add font file in your xcode project.Then add fontfile name in .plist file in "Fonts provided by application"

You can get all the font names with this

```
  NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                     [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            NSLog(@"Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to introduce the font names in the info.plist file. 
[image: You have to write font names like image below]

Then you have to use a Global class which is a NSOBject type.

In Globals.h file write

```
 @interface Globals : NSObject 


{

}

#define         SegoeRegular14         [UIFont fontWithName:@"Segoe UI" size:14];
```

Now you can use the font anywhere you want

```
_titleLabel.font = SegoeRegular14;
```

I hope it will do for you. All the best .

Comment: It would be much nicer to do a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on `UIFont` and then be able to do `[UIFont sogoeRegularWithSize:14]`.

Comment: SeguiRegular font is not available in the X-Code system font. So in order to add new font its better to implement like this.

Comment: Yes but you could use a category to make the use of the font nicer: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9464542